# Injective and surjective functions on a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, functions

Suppose we have a function $G:M_2(\mathbb R) \to S_2(\mathbb R)$ where $S_2(\mathbb R)$ is a symmetric matrix such that
$
S_2(\mathbb R) = \left\{A = \begin{bmatrix}
       a & b\\
       c & d
     \end{bmatrix}
\text{ such that } a,b,c,d \in \mathbb R \text{ and } b = c
\right\}
$
and

$G$ is defined as:

$
G\left(
\begin{bmatrix}
a & b\\
c & d
\end{bmatrix}
\right)
=
\begin{bmatrix}
a & b\\
c & d
\end{bmatrix} +
\begin{bmatrix}
a & c\\
b & d
\end{bmatrix}
$

Is $f$ surjective? injective?

---

For injective I got:

Not injective, observe
$A =
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2\\
1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$
and
$B =
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1\\
2 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$

$A \not = B$ but $f(A) = 
\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 3\\
3 & 2
\end{bmatrix}
=
f(B)
$

I am not sure how to approach for surjective. I believe that it is surjective... my start of a proof is:

Take arbitrary $D \in S_2(\mathbb R) = 
\begin{bmatrix}
x & y \\
y & z
\end{bmatrix}$

Then choose $C \in M_2(\mathbb R)$ such that:

$
\begin{bmatrix}
a & b\\
c & d
\end{bmatrix}
$

where $c + d = y$?

Comment: Your intuition is correct. Hint: $1=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, if you take arbitrary $D \in S_2(\mathbb R) = 
\begin{bmatrix}
x & y \\
y & z
\end{bmatrix},$

you can choose the following $C \in M_2(\mathbb R)$:

$
C = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{x}{2} & \frac{y}{2}\\
\frac{y}{2} & \frac{z}{2}
\end{bmatrix}.
$

It is easy to verify that $G(C) = D$, which proves that $G$ is surjective.

Answer (score 0):

If $Α$ is symmetric then $G(A)=2A$.